# Topological property of convergent sequences being eventually constant

Tags: gn.general-topology, terminology

Is there a name in the literature for the topological property that all convergent sequences are eventually constant?

This property seems to occur with some frequency and it would be nice to have a good name for it.

Some example spaces: any discrete space, the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta\omega$, the cocountable topology on an uncountable set, the one-point Lindelöfication of an uncountable discrete space, etc, etc.

Comment: Alexandroff and Urysohn called a limit of a non-trivial sequence a $\kappa$-point; so "space without $\kappa$-points"?

Comment: I realize we can't name those ourselves, but I think a good name would be "sequentially discrete space", with anology to discrete spaces. This is also seen in that the sequential coreflection of a space is discrete iff it has no non-trivial sequences.

Comment: Yes, "sequentially discrete" would be a great name.  It was at least used by Pete Clark in his answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/170335 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289736.

Comment: And also used in the literature: e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.09062.pdf, and maybe https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273880 ?

Comment: @PatrickR I think you should post an answer with all those references. Perhaps adding the proof that a space is sequentially discrete iff it has discrete sequential coreflection for completeness.

Comment: @Jakobian Will do.  Just waiting to see if anyone has any other comments.

Answer (score 6):

(Collecting some of the comments above into an answer)

There is no commonly used terminology for spaces with no non-trivial converging sequences, i.e., spaces where every converging sequence is eventually constant.

Most authors use the full description, but if we wanted a short name, "**sequentially discrete**" would be a natural choice.  This fits with the result:

> A space has no non-trivial converging sequences iff its sequential coreflection is discrete.

(Closed sets in the sequential coreflection are the sequentially closed sets in the original topology.  If every converging sequence is eventually constant, every set is sequentially closed.  Conversely, suppose every set is sequentially closed and suppose the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$.  Then $x$ must be one of the $x_n$.  Now all the elements of the sequence must eventually be equal to $x$, otherwise we could extract a subsequence of points distinct from $x$ that also converges to $x$, which is not possible.)

And in fact the "sequentially discrete" terminology has occasionally been used, as attested for example in:

- [T. Banakh & S. Gabriyelyan, 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.09062)
- [R. Dahmen, 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.09755)
- [P. Clark, 2014](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/170335)
- [P. Clark, 2013](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289736)
- [R. Dougherty, 1987](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273880), probably (don't have access)